# Meta tag to replace or equivalent to the "meta tag=refresh"

Tags: html, meta-tags, page-refresh

Is there any other meta tag that is equivalent  to replace the

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
```

this meta tag works fine but my site is not stable enough, it always keep refreshing.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.site.com.au">
```

picture shown below.It has successfully redirected to the corrected site but it  always keep refreshing and not stable enough.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6qZs.png)

It always happen to all browsers

Comment: you want to refresh a same page/ site in some interval

Comment: no..when i tried to redirect to another site.placed this code inside my <head> section: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL= url=http://www.site.com.au">

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='http://www.site.com.au'">
```

try to set the meta rate to 1 sometimes where the browser ignores 0 value meta refresh.

see [demo here](http://screencast.com/t/wiTpty99).

**Note: Place it in the head section.**

Comment: its again showing the loading ... because I have check its working for me directly after 1 sec redirect to URL

Comment: I think ill take your answers for now. i just set it for 3

Comment: @uttar.ya 3 sec is more time to reload all the page content visible to user

Comment: we need to remove the '..' character on site link cause it will allow users to back to the top once they scrolling down the pages

Comment: What do you mean ?